# When Populating a datatable the value passed to the controller is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I'm having a problem with populating the datatable based from the result of the controller.

I've read lot's of post about it but i can't figure why I'm having this error.

This is my controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SearchOrder([FromBody]SearchInfo order)
        {
            var Url = _appSettings.CashSystemAPIUrl + "api/Order/GetOrderBy";
            var r = await _repository.GetAllAsync(Url, order, HttpMethod.Post);
            var result = Json(new { data =  r});
            return result;
        }
```

And this is my model

```
public class SearchInfo
    {
        
        public int OrderType { get; set; }

        public string OrderKeyword { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is my view

```
<table id="tblOrdersData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                        
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Order Number</th>
                                <th>Invoice Number</th>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                       
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                      
                    </table>
```

And this is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnsearch').click(function () {
            var dataTable;
            var selectedValue = $("#searchCategory").val();//$("#searchCategory option:selected").text();
            
            var textboxvalue = $('#searchvalue').val()

            var SearchInfo = {};
            SearchInfo.OrderType = parseInt(selectedValue);
            SearchInfo.OrderKeyword = textboxvalue;

            dataTable = $('#tblOrdersData').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "datatype": "json",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": "/Orders/SearchOrder",
                    "datatype": JSON.stringify(SearchInfo)
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "orderNo", "width": "50%" },
                    { "data": "invoiceNo", "width": "20%" }
                ]
            });

        });
    });
    
</script>
```

And this is the screenshot of debugging

[image]

There is a value in the **OrderType** and **OrderKeyword**

but when it is passed in the controller it became null.

[image]

but when i use this code to call the controller

```
$.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Orders/SearchOrder',
            data: JSON.stringify(SearchInfo),
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error!")
            }
        });
```

The data is passed to the controller correctly

[image]

But i need a way to get the result from the controller to populate the datatable.

So why does the first javascript is passing null value to the controller? i don't understand. the code is the same to me. So why does it's null?

Thank you

**Update**

I updated the code and make it into
[image]

```
dataTable = $('#tblOrdersData').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    "datatype": 'json',
                    "type": 'POST',
                    "url": '/Orders/SearchOrder',
                    "data": JSON.stringify(SearchInfo)
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "tco", "width": "50%" },
                    { "data": "orderNo", "width": "20%" },
                    { "data": "fullPrice", "width": "20%" },

                ]
            });
```

but the controller is still receiving null.

Comment: You just need to double-check your JS code, why did you have datatype two times?

Answer (score 2):

You had written `datatype` two times, in first JS code.

You had corrected that in 2nd example which is
`data: JSON.stringify(SearchInfo),`

**Edit**

Also check `casing` of the json response element for `SearchOrder`, the json element must be same as `tco`, `orderNo` and `fullPrice`

```js
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Orders/SearchOrder',
    data: JSON.stringify(SearchInfo),
    success: function(result) {
        $('#tblOrdersData').DataTable({
            "data": result,
            "columns": [{
                    "data": "tco",
                    "width": "50%"
                },
                {
                    "data": "orderNo",
                    "width": "20%"
                },
                {
                    "data": "fullPrice",
                    "width": "20%"
                },

            ]
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error!")
    }
});
```

Comment: I updated it and the controller still receives null. I also updated the question and i put the updated code. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code now? Thank you

Comment: @audreyatwork Check the edited answer.
You can bind datatable once your receive the `result` from ajax call